# Read a json file from blob as dictionary

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have a json file which I've stored in a blob. I want to read that file as a dictionary. For a normal file system I would do it like following-

```
with open(file_path) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

But when I'm giving the blob url to open it is not working. I can use pyspark functions to read from the blob and convert it to json like below -

```
df=spark.read.json(file_url)
data = list(map(lambda row: row.asDict(True), df.collect()))[0]
```

I'm wondering if I can do this in a simple manner like above as collect operations are a bit expensive in spark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to read json from url. e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
json_data = pd.read_json("http://ip-api.com/json/54.148.84.95", typ='series')
json_data.head()
```

Comment: although this is a good alternative it doesn't work with a blob. A blob url is like this 'wasbs://container_name@blobname.blob.core.windows.net/Cities/names.json'

Comment: wasbs seems to be azure vendor specifc protocol. This blog might be of help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/explore-data-blob